# MySQL query loop to group columns in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Table1
    +----------------+-------------+
    | ID | Condition | Color       |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  1 | FAIR      | RED         |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  2 | GOOD      | Red         |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  3 | Great     | BLACK       |
    +----------------+-------------+
    | .. | ..        | ..          |
    +----------------+-------------+
```

I want to count all conditions with respect to color. So a simple query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) Total FROM Table1 WHERE Condition="FAIR" AND Color="RED"
```

this will return number of rows where condition is FAIR and color is RED. Is it possible to include all possible outcomes? So a table that gives count(id) for all conditions with a single query instead of having multiple queries?

```
    +----------------+-------------+
    | Total | Condition | Color    |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  5    | FAIR      | RED      |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  6    | FAIR      | BLUE     |
    +----------------+-------------+
    |  2    | Great     | RED      |
    +----------------+-------------+
    | ..    | ..        | ..       |
    +----------------+-------------+
```

There are set of fixed values for Condition and Color with exception of empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) Total, Condition, Color 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Condition, Color
```